# There is an error of page not found ;Request method get method

Tags: python, django

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/signup
Raised by:  django.contrib.admin.sites.catch_all_view


You’re seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change that to False, and Django will display a standard 404 page.
```

I tried on stackoverflow but it gives me the post method to solve the error

Comment: please add more context like urls.py, full error trace etc.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.